# A book about a night shift clerk in a hotel

Tags: identification-request

I am looking for a book about a night shift hotel receptionist/clerk who spent all his time reading.

He had some high powered life but after some (tragic?) event he was disillusioned by life and quit his old life. He took a night shift job at a small hotel and spent all his free time sleeping or reading, he also spent most of his job time reading (as it was a very quiet hotel).

His idyllic new life crashes down when a parcel is left at the desk which turns out to be full of money.

If I recall correctly he is faced with the dilemma of what to do with the package when it is never picked up and opens it out of curiosity. His problem is then what to do with the money...

I thought it was called Night Shift but a google search didn't seem to bring anything up... Does anyone know what it could be?

Comment: Heyo. This is a pretty good story-ID question so far! You've included a lot of detail, which is good. Is there anything else that you remember about the story? Specifically, about how long it was, or what language it was in? Including when you read it (and how new it was, at that point) can also help people figure out the book you're thinking of. (See also [this post](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/778/481) for more guidelines.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I googled around a little bit, using different search terms, and found one possibility: [***Nightwork*** by Irwin Shaw](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/515139.Nightwork). Here's the Goodreads summary:

> A dead man’s briefcase presents a down-on-his-luck pilot with the
>   chance of a lifetime.
>
> Pilot Douglas Grimes’s best days are long behind him. Grounded due to
>   a medical condition, Douglas has resigned himself to menial work as a
>   desk clerk at a seedy hotel. But his fortune flips when he discovers a
>   hotel guest dead from a heart attack and, next to him, a tube jammed
>   with hundred-dollar bills. Douglas grabs the money and, with it, the
>   chance to remake his life. In Europe, he meets Miles Fabian, an
>   elegant and erudite con man with a flair for extravagance. Fabian
>   recruits him for his latest ploy: robbing members of the idle rich.
>   But what will happen when his bad behavior catches up with him?

So you have someone who switched to a job as a hotel clerk from pilot, who finds a container with money in it while on the job, and appears to match most of the other criteria that you listed. It also has a title similar to "Night Shift."

Here's the cover (from Goodreads):

> [image]

<sub>If it helps, I think the search that finally produced this result was "[novel about night shift hotel clerk](https://www.google.com/search?&q=novel+about+night+shift+hotel+clerk)."</sub>